# Reformat Custom Date in PHP

Tags: php

So I know how to format a date in PHP, but not from a custom format.  I have a date that is a string "YYMMDD" and I want to make it "MMDDYYYY'.  strtotime doesn't seem like it would do a good job of this when the MM and DD are both low digits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up doing:

```
$expiration_date_year   = substr($matches['expiration_date'],0,2);
$expiration_date_month  = substr($matches['expiration_date'],2,2);
$expiration_date_day    = substr($matches['expiration_date'],4,2);
$expiration_date = date('m/d/Y', mktime(0,0,0,$expiration_date_month, $expiration_date_day, $expiration_date_year));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$date1 = "YYMMDD";
list($yy, $mm, $dd) = str_split($date1, 2);

// MMDDYYYY format, assuming they are all > 2000
$date2 = $mm . $dd . "20" . $yy;
```

Comment: they are not all 2000 and I do need a 4-digit year

Comment: @user239292: It's pretty easy to modify that with a simple conditional to differentiate between the 20th and 21st century...

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP >= 5.3, have a look at [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Otherwise, if you don't want to use pure string manipulation techniques, use the more primitive [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) together with [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to parse the time into a UNIX timestamp, which you can then format using `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am under-thinking this, but couldn't you just:

```
    $oldDate='040220'; // February 20th, 2004

    $year = substr($oldDate, 0,2);
    $year += $year < 50 ? 2000 : 1900;

    $date = preg_replace('/\d{2}(\d{2})(\d{2})/', '$1/$3/'.$year, $oldDate);
```

And you'd have the string you were looking for, or something close enough to it that you could modify from what I wrote here.

Answer (score 0):

Have many dates prior to 1910? If not, you could check your YY for <=10, and if true, prepend "20" else prepend "19"... Kinda similar approach to MM and DD check for <10 and prepend a "0" if true... (This is all after exploding, or substring... Assign each part to its own variable, i.e. $M=$MM; $D=$DD; $Y=$YYYY; then concatenate/arrange in whatever order you want... Just another potential way to skin the proverbial cat...